# Pricing Precision

Tags: magento-1.9, price

I need to change Magento's core pricing precision from `($price, 4)` to `($price, 8)`. However, I still need it to display as (`$price, 2)`. I sell a product that we tier in `50, 250, 500, 1000, 2000, 5000, 10000, 20000, and 50000` and my pricing needs those fractions of cents to display properly. I have read all over the web and can't figure it out. Changed Zend, Changed the core files in Magento...still no luck. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Non-answer: Magento stores prices in 4-digit precision throughout the core database tables, nevermind code. Changing that would be incredibly invasive.

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the Currency.php file at app\code\core\Mage\Directory\Model.

I changed pricing precision from 2 to 8.

> public function format($price, $options = array(), $includeContainer = true, $addBrackets = false)
>   {
>
> return $this->formatPrecision($price, 8, $options, $includeContainer, $addBrackets);
>
> }

Comment: I did that, and it is still only using 4 decimals in its math. I also made sure I updated the tables to 12, 8 just in case. It is still rounding math to the 4th decimal.

Comment: May be Third Party extension overwrite this file. Use this module conflictor for checking confliction. 

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/modules-conflict-detector.html